# Batch command to run Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: batch, visual-studio-2008

I was just trying to run `Visual Studio 2008` using a `batch` command.

`Start Notepad.exe` opens Notepad for me.

I am not sure how can I run `Visual Studio 2008` the same way.

Can anyone help me with this?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Simply find Visual studio executable in Program Files / Program Files (x86) and do the same as you are doing with Notepad.

Probable Path:  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio`  unless you've changed it upon installation.

There is a main executable there for sure.